# Sharpness of a critical line loop

Tags: complex-analysis

Denote zeros of the zeta function on the critical line as $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3, ...$, then plot critical line values $\zeta{\rho_n}$ to $\zeta{\rho_{n+1}}$ on the complex plane.  The starting and ending values will be 0, so it's a loop.  Here are the first hundred loops.

[image: critical line loops]

What's a good method for evaluating the sharpness of these loops at zero?  I wanted to sort these loops by sharpness, but my tries at derivatives, vectors, and slope approximations don't provide a sort that seems visually correct.  For example, to my eye, 6, 16, 17 look very smooth, while 13, 34, 53, 64 look very sharp.

Comment: Let $f(t) = \zeta(1/2+it)$ then $f'(t) = i\zeta'(1/2+it)$  so you want to compare $i\zeta'(\rho_n)$ and $i\zeta'(\rho_{n+1})$ or just their argument. If $\frac{i\zeta'(\rho_{n})}{i\zeta'(\rho_{n+1})}$ is strictly positive then your loop is smooth at $0$.